# import xgboost command fails

Tags: python-3.x, xgboost

Getting the following error while running import xgboost command in python 3.6.

```
--> C:\Anaconda3>python
Python 3.6.3 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Oct  6 2017, 10:25:46) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import xgboost
C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cross_validation.py:41: DeprecationWarning: This module was deprecated in version 0.18 in favor of the model_selection module into which all the refactored classes and functions are moved. Also note that the interface of the new CV iterators are different from that of this module. This module will be removed in 0.20.
  "This module will be removed in 0.20.", DeprecationWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xgboost\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .core import DMatrix, Booster
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xgboost\core.py", line 112, in <module>
    _LIB = _load_lib()
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xgboost\core.py", line 106, in _load_lib
    lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(lib_path[0])
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 426, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 348, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found
```

What could be a potential solution to resolve this issue?
I have uninstalled and reinstalled the packgage, but still the same issue..

Comment: Please update the xgboost installation

Comment: Or downgrade the scikit-learn to 0.19